# Wiki engine with private block feature

Tags: python, wiki

I'm serching for wiki engine, preferably written on python(but is not necessary), with one specific feature - user should be able to insert the block on pages, which will be visible only for one user, the author. This wiki is needed to play dungeons and dragons. Dungeon master should be able to insert a mark for himself.

*Maybe i should aks this on https://rpg.stackexchange.com/ ?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had received a answer [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/13717/wiki-engine-for-dd)

> [Moinmoin](http://moinmo.in/) would fit that bill pretty well. It has hierarchical ACL
>   which can do just what you want and is written in Python

.